# Is there a way to delete an Imgur image uploaded to Super User?

Tags: support

When using the toolbar to upload an image in a question or the answer to a question, it gets saved to the StackExchange's Imgur account. If the wrong image is uploaded, is there a way to delete it? Also, if the image is not used in any questions or answers, is it automatically deleted after a given period of time?

Comment: Normally not. Is there any private information you want to have removed?

Comment: nope, it's not deleted either

Comment: @slhck No, not really, it's just that I uploaded a screenshot but then I made a better one that I wanted to replace the old one with. I uploaded the new screenshot and just changed the URL to the new screenshot. But I have noted the URL of the old one, so I thought I would stop by and ask if it's possible to delete the old one, just to save you guys some space you know? I couldn't find any answer to this question by using the search function.

Comment: @slhck I know that the images are not hosted directly on Super User or Stack Exchange servers. But is there really no limitation on how much data you can store on the Imgur account? And what do I do if I by accident upload the wrong image from my desktop containing my personal information? Can I report it for deletion somehow?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94710/can-i-should-i-delete-unused-images-from-imgur

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If the wrong image is uploaded, is there a way to delete it?

Not officially. The imgur server for Stack Exchange more or less belongs to them though, so deletion is possible, but you would need a developer to do that for you.

> What do I do if I by accident upload the wrong image from my desktop containing my personal information? Can I report it for deletion somehow?

I'm not sure if the [official imgur deletion request form](https://imgur.com/removalrequest) works for content uploaded through Stack Exchange.

If you've uploaded an image that contains private information which you would like to remove, please get in touch with us moderators or contact the Stack Exchange team through `team at stackexchange.com`. Contacting the team via e-mail would be preferable so as not to share the link to the image across the network (e.g. chat, comments), where others could see it.

> Also, if the image is not used in any questions or answers, is it automatically deleted after a given period of time?

No. The whole point of using a dedicated Stack server with imgur is that information is not lost after a certain amount of time.

> But is there really no limitation on how much data you can store on the Imgur account?

I'm fairly certain storage space is not an issue these days and Stack Exchange will make sure we can include as many pictures of unicorns, kittens and waffles as we want in our posts.

Comment: kittens and waffles, you are making me hungry.

Comment: **@Moab:** Mentioning *kittens* make you hungry - you have strange cravings...